# Casson invariant and signature

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, qa.quantum-algebra, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

In W. Neumann, J. Wahl, "Casson invariant of links of singularities", 
Comment. Math. Helv.,1990, Vol. 65, Issue 1, pp 58-78 some connection between the Casson invariant and the signature is formulated. Is there any heuristic explanation, why such a connection should be? The only reason I see is the Rokhlin invariant, which is defined by the signature and is reduction mod 2 of the Casson invariant. I would be happy to find some arguments in terms of Donaldson invariants or something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andras Nemethi and I have considerably generalized this result to  rational homology $3$-spheres that are links of certain isolated surface singularities.

A rational homology $3$-sphere $M$ which is the link of an isolated surface singularity is equipped with a canonical  spin-c structure.   Associated to this  spin-c structure  is a Seiberg-Witten invariant which can be alternatively described    in terms of  the Casson-Walker invariant  and the  refined Reidemeister torsion as defined by Turaev; [see this reference](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/SWrat.pdf).  If the $3$-manifold $M$ is an integral homology sphere, then it has a unique spin-c structure whose  Seiberg-Witen invariant coincides with the Cason invariant.

In a  sequence of papers (see [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/SWsingI.pdf), [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/SWsingII.pdf) and [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/SWsingIII.pdf)) A. Nemethi and I proved  that for many  classes of isolated singularities  whose links are rational homology $3$-spheres, the Seiberg-Witten invariant of the  above canonical spin-c structure of the link coincides with a certain algebraic  geometric invariant of the singularity   (essentially the geometric genus).

If the singularity happens to be  a complete intersection, then this   algebraic-geometric invariant can be expressed in terms of the signature of the Milnor fiber.     Brieskorn integral homology spheres are of this type,   and when specialized to this case,   our result  coincides  Neumann and Wahl's older result.

I want to emphasize that our result applies even to situations when the singularity is not smoothable, i.e., Milnor fiber does not exist. (Most of the time the Milnor fiber does not exist.)

You can find a gentler introduction to this topic [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/swsing.pdf).